# Access $? Variable with a piped statement?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have some code that I would like to have the $? variable of.

```
VARIABLE=`grep "searched_string" test.log | sed 's/searched/found/'`
```

Is there any way to test if this entire line (rather than just the sed command) was completed successfully? If I try the following code right after it:

```
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
then 
    echo 1
    exit
fi
```

it doesn't run even if the grep part of the statement fails.

Could someone show how to resolve this issue?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the

```
echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
```

will print out the array of exit-statuses of all commands.

```
$ ls | grep . | wc -l
    28
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 0 0
```

but

```
$ ls | grep nonexistentfilename | wc -l
      0
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 1 0    #the grep returns 1 - pattern not found
```

or

```
$ ls nonexistentfilename | grep somegibberish | wc -l
ls: nonexistentfilename: No such file or directory
      0
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
1 1 0   #ls and grep fails
```

for exact command status

```
echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}  #for the grep
```

also here is the

```
set -o pipefail
```

from the docs

> **pipefail**
>
> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the
>   last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if
>   all commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is
>   disabled by default.

```
$ ls nonexistentfile | wc -c
ls: nonexistentfile: No such file or directory
        0 
$ echo $?
0

$ set -o pipefail
$ ls nonexistentfile | wc -c
ls: nonexistentfile: No such file or directory
        0 
$ echo $?
1
```

### EDIT based on the comment

Youre probably tried the next:

```
VARIABLE=$(grep "searched_string" test.log | sed 's/searched/found/')
echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

Of course, this can't work because the whole `$(...)` part runs in the subshell (another process) and therefore any variable what is created is lost when the subshell exits. (at the `)`)

You should put the whole PIPESTATUS mechanism into `$(...)` like next:

```
variable=$(
        grep "searched_string" test.log | sed 's/searched/found/'

        # do something with PIPESTATUS
        # you should not echo anythig to stdout (because will be captured into $variable)
        # you can echo on stderr - e.g.
        echo "=${PIPESTATUS[@]}=" >&2
)
```

Also, the second line of the comment is an solution, eg:

```
var_with_status=$(command | commmand2 ; echo ":DELIMITER:${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
```

now, the `$var_with_status` will contain not only the result of the `command | command2` but the PIPESTATUS too, delimited with some unique delimiter, so you can extract it...

Also, the `set -o pipefail` will indicate the result - if you don't need exact place of the fail.

Also you can write the PIPESTATUS in some temp-file (in the subshell) and the parent can read it and delete the temp-file...

Also is possible print the PIPESTATUS into different file-descriptors in the subshell and read this descriptor in the parent shell, but....

... beware do not fall into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you will make extremelly complicated script, only because you don't want change the logic of the processing.

e.g. you can always break you script into safe parts, like:

```
var1=$(grep 'str' test.log)
#check the `$var1` and do something with the error indicated with `$?`
var2=(sed '....' <<<"$var1")
#check the `$var2` and do something with the error indicated with `$?`
#and so on
```

simple enough?

So, ask yourself - do you really need mungling with how to get the PIPESTATUS form an subshell?

*Ps: don't use uppercase variable names. could interfere with some environment variables and causes hard-to-debug problems..*

Comment: However, I've had problems with the whole VARIABLE= part. That makes it so that it doesn't give me what I want for the piped output... is there any way around that?